# Is Wiener amalgam spaces $W^{2,1}(\mathbb R)\subset C_0(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I have been learning [Wiener amalgam spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_amalgam_space).

In Wiener amalgam spaces $W(X, L^2)$, I am taking $X=\mathcal{F}L^{1}=\{f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R):\hat{f}\in L^{1}\},$ and $m(x)=1.$

Take $f(x)= \chi_{\mathbb Q}(x), x\in \mathbb R.$ clearly, $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R).$

> **My Question are**: 
>   (1)Is $f\in W(\mathcal{F}L^{1}(\mathbb R), L^{2}(\mathbb R))$?
>
> (2) If we get negative answer in the first then my question is : is it true that (i) $W(\mathcal{F}L^{1}(\mathbb R), L^{2}(\mathbb R)) \subset C(\mathbb R)$ (ii) $W(\mathcal{F}L^{1}(\mathbb R), L^{2}(\mathbb R)) \subset C_0(\mathbb R)$(= continuous functions  vanishing at infinity)?

Edit: $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=0$ otherwise

Comment: Um, if you're using Lebesgue measure, $f$ is clearly *not* in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  Also, if I'm reading the Wikipedia page correctly, the space $W(X, L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ should be a space of $X$-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}$-valued.

Comment: I'm still confused.  For the Wikipedia definition to make sense, we should have $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{F} L^1$.  But you have $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ it seems.  (And if you mean that $f(x)$ is the constant function 1 when $x$ is rational, note that $1$ is not in $\mathcal{F} L^1$ since its Fourier transform is not a function.)  Anyway, it seems pretty clear from the definition that it's not affected by null sets, so any appropriate function that vanishes off the rationals would trivially be in $W(X, L^p)$.